# API Call in C# (CsCart)

Tags: c#, api

I'm trying to call an API via C# but I get the error that my string is not a URI.

```
string url = "@http://api@myAddress.com:API_KEY@myAddress.com/api.php?_d=products&ajax_custom=1";
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
            return webResp.ToString();
```

It works well when I put the request in the address bar though...

Comment: What's with the @ at the front of the string? Did you mean to use a verbatim string where you put the @ *before* the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move @ out of the string literal:

```
string url = @"http://api@myAddress.com:API_KEY@myAddress.com/api.php?_d=products&ajax_custom=1";
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
WebResponse webResp = webRequest.GetResponse();
return webResp.ToString();
```